# Is there support for 8bits per channel and 16bits per channel UAV in a compute shader?

Tags: directx, hlsl, directcompute

I'm working on a compute shader. It needs to output some textures as UAVs. Some of them have 8bits components and some have 16bits per channel. Consider this line:

```
RWTexture2D<float4> _watNormTex;
```

I bind a R8G8B8A8_UNORM texture to it and the output is black but when I bind a R32G32B32A32_FLOAT texture it saves the correct values. So it seems it has a problem with texture format.

What can I do to output to 8bit or 16bit per channel textures?

**PS:** My test device has a G[eforce 710 GT](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-710) GPU.

Comment: Do you have debug layer enabled? It should provide you some information in case something is wrong, also without posting any code it's gonna be difficult to source the error (as a side note I tried your case and it worked with both formats, so I would think something is wrong in your pipeline setup).

Comment: @catflier You are absolutely right. It was a framework setup problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a setup problem as @catflier suggested. The formats should work as expected.